# Secondary hard drive making screeching sound while restarting

Tags: boot, grub2, sound, hard-drive

### Configuration

This issue is regarding my HP laptop where I have a primary SSD as /dev/sda and a secondary 1TB WD 2.5inch Hard drive installed using a hard drive caddy in place of the DVD drive by removing it.

I have a dual boot system, Linux and Windows, both installed in the SSD(/dev/sda)
I have other files not related to OS in the secondary Hard Drive(/dev/sdb), there are three partitions in it.

### Issue

When I restart my computer from Linux or from the Grub menu, as soon as it enters the BIOS POST, a screeching sound is made by the secondary hard drive probably by the moving head.

This sound occurs irrespective of Linux distros(Tried Ubuntu, Manjaro, Fedora, etc)
This sound does not occur if I shutdown from Linux and then turn it on again. Also, this sound does not occur if I restart from Windows.

The hard drive works fine apart from the initial sound, with no I/O or bad sector error.

### What I tried so far

After searching the internet I tried hdparm -B 255 /dev/sdb to disable power saving mode
explained in the below article

[Hard drive louder in Linux](https://superuser.com/questions/395609/hard-drive-louder-in-linux/415189#415189)

This did not solve the issue.

I am afraid this issue might eventually damage my Hard drive in the long run.

Any help will be highly appreciated. Thanks in advance

Comment: Whenever a hard drive makes a sound I tend to believe it is a hardware problem, nothing to do with Ubuntu.

Comment: Yes, I understand that, but as I mentioned it doesn't make any sound in Windows and also this is not only related to Ubuntu but all other Linux distros, as the Ubintu user base seems to be large I tried finding answer here.

Comment: I am having this issue in Ubuntu latest LTS as well as Non LTS version and I am here finding solutions not fight in a silly way to where to reach out for. Your argument is not helping me.